# Mule 3 LDAP connector multiple Base DN

Tags: active-directory, ldap, mule

In Mule 3 LDAP connector, how can I provide multiple Base DN?

The users are in Active Directory.

For example all the below 3. Are there any separators?

If I give each one of them separately it works but validates only users in that directory.

OU=USERS,OU=DEPARTMENT1,DC=bbc,DC=com
OU=USERS,OU=DEPARTMENT2,DC=bbc,DC=com
OU=USERS,OU=DEPARTMENT3,DC=bbc,DC=com

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is a way to provide multiple baseDNs. However, you could wrap each connector in a message enricher for a payload of all 3 search results.